# Did Saddam Hussein have a Quran written in blood?

Tags: politics, religion, religious-texts, iraq, quran

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_Quran
http://www.theguardian.com/world/2010/dec/19/saddam-legacy-quran-iraqi-government

"The "Blood Qur'an" is a copy of the Islamic holy book, the Qur'an, claimed to have been written in the blood of the former Iraqi president Saddam Hussein over the course of two years in the late 1990s."

This was in most major newspapers. It's quite specific, there's some photos, and apparently it was on semi-public display for years.

But none of the news articles have much in the way of citations. Was it publicly known in Iraq before those articles? What happened to it? Are there any accounts from people who saw it?

Is it really true? It seems like it should be obvious, but a little googling didn't turn anything up.

NB: I'm curious whether the book exists. I understand it may be impossible to prove it's *actually* written in blood or not, let alone Saddam Hussein's blood.

Comment: If the book exists and someone would be able to take samples of the writing, wouldn't it be trivial with a DNA analysis to prove that the book was written with Saddam Husseins blood?

Comment: @Tor-EinarJarnbjo Might not be trivial- depends if doing a DNA analysis on a holy book is blasphemous.

Comment: Four years later and I still have no idea. I understand that, if such a book exists, people can debate or measure it's authenticity. But does the book like that exist, whether or not it's authentically written in blood? Or was in an made up Iraqi article somewhere which was mistakenly re-reported in western newspapers?